# Filter non alphanumeric characters while reading line in C++?

Tags: c++, inputstream, user-input

Is it possible to read alphanumeric characters only from the given input line ignoring everything else in C/C++? I am trying to read whole line at a time.

Suppose we have to read the line:

```
 aaa, bbb, ccc .
```

Here, my intention is to ignore comma, dot and space while taking input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in several ways, for example the simplest is to read the whole line and then remove the bits you don't want later:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
  std::string line;
  while (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
    line.erase(std::remove_if(line.begin(), line.end(), std::not1(std::ptr_fun(isalnum))), line.end());
    std::cout << line << "\n";
  }
}
```

Reads a line and then removes any characters which return false for `isalnum`. (In C++11 you can simplify this slightly)

Comment: That's what I was trying to do, but I couldn't get it to work :p

Answer (score -2):

you could write a string array and use the comma, dot, and space as string seperators.  Store each string in the array and then output it.

```
aaa, bbb, ccc .

aaa will be stored in string[0]
bbb will be stored in string[1]
ccc will be stored in string[2]
```

then just output the strings through a for loop and you'll get

aabbcc

Comment: I have to ignore all non alphanumeric characters in addition to comman, dot and space.